# Partial response of 1.8inch TFT screen with arduino

Tags: arduino, spi, lcd

I am trying my hands on LCD screens. So I chose this [1.8-inch TFT LCD screen](http://www.tinylcd.com/tiny149/product.php?id_product=13) and tested the same with the TM4c123gxl board using an ST7735 library (adapted from Adafruit) and the screen works perfectly as expected. ([Tiva Series 1.8' LCD code](https://github.com/mayankshukla91/testCode)).

So for some other project, I plan to use the same screen but with Arduino UNO. So I connected the same and tried to test the graphicstest example packaged with Adafruit library, but unfortunately, it's not working as expected as you can see in the [video](https://youtu.be/OHUHUZR3jOg).

I am using resistor divider network to shift the voltage from 5V logic to 3V. [image: Voltage shift]

I have checked the SPI lines with a logic sniffer and they seem to work as expected. And this cannot be noise because it been repeatedly programmed and the behaviour is exactly the same as in the video.

What I am able to conclude is probably I am missing something with configuration 
but I have compared the Tiva and Arduino library file and they both seem to configure the LCD with identical values.

So any direction would be of great help since I am out of ideas.

Comment: What is the speed you are using? I have tested on another spi display that if the equivalent resistor \$\frac {R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ is 10k, the maximum frequency you can use is about 1 MHz, due to stray capacitances. Your equivalent resistor is about 3k, so you can't go faster than 3 MHz. If you use a 1k + 1.5k resistor divider,you should go up to the maximum ATMEGA328P SPI speed of 8MHz.

Comment: I know it's not the solution but i powered the arduino directly from 4.7V (ST7735 is tolerant to 4.7V) and the whole thing worked like charm. Will update the final solution once done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected the issue was with the library itself and not with the hardware.

Instead of using Adafruit ST7735 and Adafruit GFX library I used default TFT library provided with Arduino and it worked like a charm.

And this problem is very erratic. Because at times it works with certain LCD's, sometimes during bootup of Arduino you can see a flash of what it was supposed to display. But TFT library works with the LCD very well every time.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZ6oAqTX5fg&feature=youtu.be&t=186. This video is what lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The LCD you are using is a 3.3V part. The Tiva Launchpad is also a 3.3V part. However, the Arduino Uno is a 5V part.

You are supplying the LCD with too high a voltage -- quite frankly, you're lucky it is working at all. Use a level shifter, or use a 5V compatible LCD.

Comment: Hey, I forgot to mention that I am dropping the voltage using a resistor network (https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/high_to_low_level_translator.png) and have observed the waveform on DSO and its around 3V.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor values of your divider seem to be too high, unless your SPI speed is set to a very low frequency.

I have tested on [another SPI display](https://next-hack.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/A0Fig1a.png) that, due to stray capacitances, if the equivalent resistor  \$\frac {R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ is \$10\ k\Omega\$, then the maximum reliable SPI speed is 1MHz.

Your display + PCB might of course might have different stray capacitances, but I don't expect a variation larger than an order of magnitude.

Your equivalent resistor is about \$3\ k\Omega\$. This would yield in my case a maximum speed of 3.3 MHz (i.e. 2 MHz on Arduino Uno).

**possible solutions:**

- Use a resistor divider \$R_1=1\ k\Omega\$ and \$R_2=1.5\ k\Omega\$.
- If it does not work, or if you don't feel like of having an additional curent consumption of some mA:

  1. check the maximum SPI speed \$f_{max}\$ at which your display works.
  2. Calculate \$k = \frac {f_{desired}}{f_{max}}\$
  3. divide both resistors by k.

Comment: Hi @next-hack. I did try with 1k and 1.5k resistor, but no luck. But I think your idea may lead me in the right direction. Because viewing the signals on DSO show capacitive behaviour (gradual rising and falling signals rather than sharp signal) May i know how did you calculate the maximum speed with the help of resistors?

Comment: as of now I don't mind the excess current because in final circuit I plan to use a buffer (as shown in adafruit page). Driving the buffer at 3.3V and shifting the V levels to 3.3V.

Comment: Just trial and error :) One question: if you set an SPI speed of, say 250 kHz, does it work?

Comment: I didnt try that....let me give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: No luck. I tried with 250kHz clock frequency. Same results, just slower updates. (results:- https://ibb.co/mD0M0b)

Comment: What I am able to conclude is there is something wrong with the configuration file and not with the SPI communication.

Comment: Could you post also the source code in your question? Also, did you connect the reset, CS, and the D/C (through a divider)? Can you check the voltages?

Comment: I am using "graphicstest" sample code from Adafruit ST3775 driver library (https://learn.adafruit.com/1-8-tft-display/downloads). And yes I have connected reset and D/C (through divider), CS I have directly grounded since I was out of resistors. Voltage levels are at 3V as expected. And the original code which is working with Tiva is also linked in the question (shared on github).

Comment: The CS should not be always grounded, as it is used as "Start of frame". In this way the display controller knows when you are sending the first byte of the command. You could try for the CS "any" (e.g. 10-15k) resistor pair that gives the 3/5 ratio, and use a very slow clock frequency, and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66461/discussion-between-mayank-and-next-hack).